# Develop an Existing Python Package

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, setuptools

I am trying to fix some bugs of an open source package on Github. So I git clone the fork to my local directory. The question is that how I can override the installed version with the version that I am developing.

Note:
1. This particular package does not support the setup.py develop command
2. This particular package is managed by Anaconda's conda. I have other packages in the same situation that is managed by pip

Comment: Import by giving path.

Comment: @IngeniousTechie, can you show in an answer how to import by giving a path?

Comment: It will also be nice if you do a pull request so they can apply that bug fix to the official version of the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Just use:

```
pip install -e
```

Answer (score 0):

When you install a package it resides in `<env dir>lib/python3.4/site-packages/<Any package>` or you can place it in your app and import it in code.

If you have mongoengine code in your my_lib directory you can import it like

```
from my_lib import mongoengine
```

Comment: This does not really solve the problem, because the code that uses the package is not under my control. I need my package to override the original package when python is searching for packages. I cannot uninstall the original package either, because it will mess up the package managers like conda and pip

Comment: What issue you facing after this?

Comment: I cannot go into the code that I don't have control and change every import mongoengine to from my_lib mongoengine